# Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am trying to run a sample code and same code was absolutely fine yesterday and Today,It started throwing following error , any ideas to solve this problem?
I tried cleaning. Stopping all processes related to the application , nothing worked :(

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy "obj\Debug\TodoREST.dll" to "bin\Debug\TodoREST.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.    TodoRESTWS          
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Build action 'EmbeddedResource' is not supported by one or more of the project's targets.   TodoASMX    C:\Users\wadhw\Downloads\TodoASMX\TodoASMX\Views\TodoListPage.xaml  0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you working with Visual Studio? This is a known bug, an update was released yesterday to fix it.

You can see the release notes [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).

Which say:

> Compilation fails because process cannot access dll (after VS2017 update
>   2 (v15.2))

Although I now see that the error message is slightly different. You can also try this:

- Close VS (or whatever)
- Go to your code on the filesystem
- Delete all the `bin` and `obj` folders in each of the project folders

Now open up your IDE again and try to rebuild.

Comment: Yes, I am working with VS and I installed all recommended updates, Its gone now. Thanks Gerald :)

Comment: Still happening the same issue with VS2019 v16.8.2

Comment: happened today w vs code.   not sure what made this appear all the sudden.

Comment: not work for VS2019 :(

Comment: Yes, unfortunately there is the classic the 'action can't be completed because the folder or a file in it is open in another program' error

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your bin folder in your project it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).